# When to validate paypal IPN when using a queue?

Tags: validation, paypal, queue, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

When is it recommended to validate the paypal IPN?

**Option 1** - Validate during the handler ipn post, then save and enqueue ipn if valid.

- Pros: An attacker can not fill your database by sending fake IPNs
- Cons:

  - Requires a longer response time for ipn post since you need to
    make a web request to validate, before being able to respond with a 200 OK in the ipn handler
  - An attacker can keep your web server busy trying to validate fake IPNs

**Option 2** - Delay validation, save and enqueue ipn, respond with 200, then validate when processing the queue.

- Pros: Quick response to paypal IPN
- Cons: An attacker can fill your database by sending fake IPNs

Or do you do have something additional in place that avoids the problems of these two options?

Edit: I'm using the Paypal Adaptive Payments API, and am wondering what the recommended practice is while using that API.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal now supports sending shared secrets instead of postback validation. I prefer this provided (a) your buttons use HTTPS when posting and (a) your `notify_url` uses HTTPS.

Postback validation has a number of problems, starting with the requirement that the same POST variables be used in the same order. This isn't implementable e.g. in servlets where you don't have that level of control. However in fact it doesn't appear to actually matter, which casts doubt on other security aspects of the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is the first I heard about shared secrets.  Will this work with the Paypal Adaptive Payments API?  A quick search shows that "Encrypted Website Payments" is required, and I could only find documentation for that in the context of paypal buttons, but I'd like to use shared secrets if it is compatible the with Adaptive Payments API.

Comment: I only just discovered this myself today. I didn't get the impression that Encrypted Website Payments was required, only recommended. It's documented in the new IPN documentation.